# RXJS PostgreSQL backpressure in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, rxjs

Original title: How to slow down PgSQL results rows stream in javascript?

I'm experiencing out of memory issue in nodejs v4.5.0 with RXJS(5.4.0) and PostgreSQL (driver "pg": "6.1.4").

I manually create an observable of PgSQL rows like this:

```
return Rx.Observable.create((subscriber) => {
    pool.connect().then((client: pg.Client) => {
        const stream:any = client.query(query.toParam());
        stream.on('row', (row) => {
            subscriber.next(row);
        });

        stream.on('end', () => {
            subscriber.complete();
            client.release();
        });
    });
});
```

Then I'm attaching some operators to the rx observable and doing some processing.
Note that the rows returned from database are a bit heavy.

Investigation leads me to one conclusion:
**Rows from database are returned much faster then they can be processed. There must be memory reserved for that heavy data in order to wait for processing, and this cause out of memory issue:**

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Abort trap: 6

I don't see any option on PostgreSQL driver to pause the stream. Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your original query getting more columns than necessary? Sometimes "select *" is a bad idea on large result sets.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much room for optimisation at SQL query level. One column contains essential data and that's the heavy one.

Comment: You have to page your data reads, that's all. Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for that.

Comment: Use a CURSOR and get just a handful of results before you get the next portion.

Comment: CUROSR is a PL/pgSQL feature but in my case I need to retrieve data into javascript context.

Comment: LIMIT and OFFSET could be solution but it's not really fit into reactive programming and observable creation. It would be a complicating solution, hard to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [`pg-cursor` library](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-cursor) by the same author it should be relatively straight forward:

```
return Rx.Observable.defer(() => pg.connect())
  .flatMap(client => {
    const cursor = client.query(new Cursor('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE prop > $1', [100]))

    const observableCursor = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(cursor.read.bind(cursor));

    // Get the first 100 items
    observableCursor(100)
      .map(processRows)
      // This will only emit after the first one completes
      // and will recursively call this for each result
      .expand(_ => 
        observableCursor(100)
          .map(processRows)
      )
      // Unsubscribes once we don't get any more results
      .takeWhile(rows => rows.length > 0)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write suggested by @paulpdaniels solution as much readable as I can, but I'm not sure if this is really reactive style.

I've also have a different processing functions that depends on context variable. I like to have an architecture that easily let use different rxjs operators chain that depends on context conditions and hide the cursor.read logic but I'm affraid it's not possible.

There must be a place when I explicitly tell database to bring next bulk of data (cursor.read) and it must the place after I release memory from the heavy data.

Following solution is in typescript:

```
const db = require('./libs/db.js');
import * as Cursor from 'pg-cursor';
import * as pg from 'pg';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

let cursor, readHandler;

const source = Rx.Observable.create((subscriber) => {
    db.getClient().then((client: pg.Client) => {

        cursor = client.query(new Cursor('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE prop > $1', [100]));
        readHandler = function (err, rowsBulk) {
            if (err) {
                subscriber.error(err);
                return client.release();
            }
            if (!rowsBulk.length) {
                subscriber.complete();
                return client.release();
            }
            subscriber.next(rowsBulk);
        };
    }).then(() => {
        // fetch first 100 records
        cursor.read(100, readHandler);
    });
});

source.flatMap((item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('processing batch of items');
        setTimeout(() => { // timeout simulates processing
            item = null;
            console.log('release memory');
            resolve({});
        }, 5000);
    });
}).map(() => {
    // fetch every next 100 records
    console.log('allocate new memory');
    cursor.read(100, readHandler);
    return '.';
}).subscribe(console.log, (err) => {
    console.log('Error occurred');
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Maybe expand on "a different processing functions that depends on context variable" in your question. I can update my answer but only if you give something more concrete.

Comment: I've updated title and marked your message. I agree with passing context object as a param into the processing function.